# Run Electron UI on different port

Tags: electron

Is there a way to run an Electron app's UI on a different port? I have an app server (Wildfly) running on port 8080 and when I start the Electron app the app server default page is shown within the Electron app window. I believe that Electron runs on port 8080 in the background. Is there a way to change that to i.e. port 9000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Electron app is basically a Chromium browser with NodeJS support which loads any file you want to display from disk. It does not start any server (neither HTTP nor anything else).

With "default app page" I believe you mean the [`index.html` file of the electron-quick-start project](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/index.html). This file, for example, gets loaded in [`main.js`, line 16](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L16) using Electron's [`BrowserWindow#loadFile (...)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) function. This basically behaves equivalently to loading it using `#loadURL ("file:///...")` or by using `file://` in your browser to load any file from disk.